# What is the equivalent of GDB's “define” in LLDB?

Tags: c++, macos, gdb, lldb

I would like to define a LLDB function that runs 2 commands at the same time (for instance, print variable value and go to next line). Debugging C code using GDB I would do this:

```
(gdb) def f
Type commands for definition of "f".
End with a line saying just "end".
>p i
>n
>end
(gdb) f
```

But trying the same with LLDB doesn't work:

```
(lldb) def f
error: 'def' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'def'.
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html:

> lldb also has a built-in Python interpreter, which is accessible by the "script" command. All the functionality of the debugger is available as classes in the Python interpreter, so the more complex commands that in gdb you would introduce with the "define" command can be done by writing Python functions using the lldb-Python library, then loading the scripts into your running session and accessing them with the "script" command.